# Combine multiple lines in a RDD to a single line

Tags: scala, apache-spark, text-files, rdd

I have the following scenario:
val rdd = sc.textFile("textfile");

"textfile" is a multi line file. All I need is to concatenate multiple lines into a single line before saving it back again in a file format.

I researched a lot around this. However, couldnt find a solution to the problem.

Thanks a lot for all your help

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: Don't use Spark. In almost all scenarios, just a simple pass through the file removing line ending is going to be faster

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce like so:

`rdd.reduce((a,b) = a + b)` or more concisely `rdd.reduce(_ + _)`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Want to clarify one aspect: aren't reduce operation gonna act on data that are numerical? In my case, the text file has just text data in them.

Comment: It works on any type which has an operator which can satisfy (T,T) => T. The `+` operator is overloaded for `Strings`, giving us (String, String) => String

Comment: Keep in mind that reduce pulls the result onto the driver, so this won't work if the file is large.

Comment: @puhlen given the OP will end up with one enormous line, it is going to have to fit in the driver eventually regardless of approach.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul This is not true.  OP wants a single giant line in a file, not in memory.  The whole line doesn't need to be in memory at once.

Comment: Ok, granted. I  was assuming spark. As I put in a comment to the question, it's a problem best solved outside of Spark anyway...